# Lets Encrypt with Plesk

Tags: ssl-certificate, plesk, plesk-onyx

I am trying to install a Let's Encrypt SSL certificate to a subscription held on a Plesk install.

I am running the following version of Plesk;

> Plesk Onyx Version 17.8.11 Update #11

I then navigate to

> Subscriptions > Domain > Lets Encrypt

From the setup screen I do not change anything, so

'Include a "www" subdomain for the domain and each selected alias'

and

'Secure webmail on this domain'

Remain unchecked. However, when I try to install the cert I get the following error;

```
Error: Could not issue a Let's Encrypt SSL/TLS certificate for domain.org.

The authorization token is not available at http://example.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/key.
The token file 'C:\Inetpub\vhosts\example.com\httpdocs\\.well-known\acme-challenge\key' is either unreadable or does not have the read permission.
To resolve the issue, correct the permissions on the token file to make it is possible to download it via the above URL.
See the related Knowledge Base article for details.
Details
Invalid response from https://acme-v01.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/authz/umis0L7-OVlu7SrSjMFHBsu-T7Cx0hwFS-WMxHgZgNA.
Details:
Type: urn:acme:error:unauthorized
Status: 403
Detail: Invalid response from http://example.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/key: "<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-sc"
```

It give a link to the following KB;

[Plesk Suggested KB article](https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000191654)

Which suggest I check the DNS resovles, so `ipconfig` shows me that the domain is pointing to the right IP.

However I dont have the ability for IPv6 and when i go to

> domains > example.com> Web Hosting Access

I do not have the ability to select this.

Now from RDP to the server and looking I can see the directory structure is created i..e

> .well-known > acme-challenge > key file

is created? Can anyone help with what the issue could be here please?

Answer (score 0):

Check if the domain name resolves to IPv6 or not:
dig AAAA google.com @8.8.8.8

Check permissions for token file well-known > acme-challenge > key file
Try to access this file via browser, or create a new test text file inside of the acme-challenge folder and try to access it. There is a possibility that web.config file can cause the issue.